# DropLeft 's position is wrong

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I designed a navbar with bootstrap4.in the right side of navbar I have my links.
when I place a drop left on the navbar, the drop left opens in the wrong place.
What is the problem?

my HTML:

```
   <li class="nav-item dropleft">

            <button class="btn bg-white nav-link text-dark dropdown-toggle" id="dd" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >MORE</button>

             <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dd">
                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">sadasd</a>
            </div>

    </li>
```

This is What happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yakc3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in Bootstrap 4.0.0: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25304

As you can see in the comments, it's unknown if dropleft/right will be supported inside the navbar because of the way the popper.js positioning works.

This affects dropup, dropleft and dropright.